# How to flush all files to hard drive so even WinRAR can archive them?

Tags: c#, windows, file, winapi, winrar

I want to flush all cached files (logs in particular) to hard drive. When my software has an error I want to have complete log files and collect them for debugging.

**I'm using WinRAR to collect them.** (You can open the cached files with notepad but WinRar can't find them for some reason) But when an error occurs and I try to rar all files that are interesting for debugging, it's not able to collect the very last log file that is still open for appending.

I know I could use [`FlushFileBuffers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx) for that one file. But what if I have a few of them and other files and and and ? Is there another way to finish file writing ? It doesn't matter if it takes too long. It's in case of errors/emergencies.

**Edit:**

- There are also some images that are saved in case of errors to *.bmp.
- I use `File.AppendText(...)` for Logs.

**Another Edit:**

- to rar my latest log file (solving it for me), see accepted answer
- to flush **all** files for WinRar to be able to archive, I probably must make sure they are all closed for this operation.

**Solutions:**

- Close open files (working)
- use WinRar with the switch `-dh` (not verified)

Comment: How do you write the file? If you're using `StreamWriter` you can use `Flush` method of it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `File.AppendText()` for logs.

Comment: You need to close the files rather than flush them

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I noticed that, too. WinRar gets the log file when I close it. I just use the logging in a "volatile style" (write into log file from any thread at any time). Can't accept comments though.

Comment: WinRAR has also the switch `-dh` which makes it possible to archive a file which is currently opened by an application for writing. It should not be used here as it is always better to close each log file before archiving as this flushes the file stream buffer to storage media. But I nevertheless wanted to add this possibility. Please note that even with switch `-dh` read access to file must be possible. For more details about `-dh` take a look on `Rar.txt` in program files folder of WinRAR or in help of WinRAR.

Comment: @Mofi I missed this switch because the help of `cmd.exe -> rar.exe` said only "Gemeinsame Dateien öffnen" in German and that is saying absolutely nothing to me. I bet it has a better description in English. And yes, `"Rar.txt"` is a better helper. Sounds good, but I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you need to flush. Flushing is the process of pushing cached or buffered data to their true storage location. In this case the disk.

But your problem is that the file is open with a sharing mode that prevents WinRAR from adding the file to the archive. So, the solution to your problem is to close the file, and the perform the archiving.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly implementation of your file operations, but you may inherit your logwriters and other "write to file" stuff from `IDisposable` interface. This will require you to implement `Dispose` method which has to be called each time when object destructs. Inside `Dispose` method you have to do all stuff required for flushing data to file.